# Plotly subplots with nested shared xaxis

Tags: python, plotly

I want to generate a `plotly` plot with two subplots with a shared nested xaxis. Unfortunately I have the problem that

1. either the separators for the nested xaxis are also shown in the first plot
2. or the vertical grid lines of the two subplots don't match.

How can I either remove the separators in case 1 or match the grids between the subplots in case 2?

Case 1: Some weird long group separators in the `row=1, col=1` subplot

[image]

Case 2: The vertical grid lines of both plots don't match

[image]

The only difference between both plots is that I commented out the `x=xlabels,` line for `df_one` in the following MWE:

```
# MWE
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# generate data
idx_one = ["A", "B"]
idx_two = ["long text A", "long text B"]

df_one = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.random.rand(4,1),
    columns=["df_one"],
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([idx_one, idx_two]),
)

df_two = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.random.rand(4,1),
    columns=["df_two"],
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([idx_one, idx_two]),
)

xlabels = [
    df_one.index.get_level_values(0).tolist(),
    df_one.index.get_level_values(1).tolist(),
]

# plotly

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, y_title="some shared y-title")

fig.append_trace(
    go.Bar(
        y=df_one["df_one"],
        x=xlabels,
        name="df_one",
        showlegend=False,
        text=df_one["df_one"],
        textposition='auto',
        textangle=0,
        texttemplate='%{text:+.1f}',
    ),
    row=1, col=1,
)

fig.append_trace(
    go.Bar(
        y=df_two["df_two"],
        x=xlabels,
        name="df_two",
        showlegend=False,
        text=df_two["df_two"],
        textposition='auto',
        textangle=0,
        texttemplate='%{text:+.1f}',
    ),
    row=2, col=1,
)

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a bit unintuitive answer by setting the x values in the first `bar` plot and offsetting the bars with the `offset` option and later changing the `range` with `update_xaxes`.

Result:

[image]

Solution:

```
# MWE
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# generate data
idx_one = ["A", "B"]
idx_two = ["long text A", "long text B"]

df_one = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.random.rand(4,1),
    columns=["df_one"],
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([idx_one, idx_two]),
)

df_two = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.random.rand(4,1),
    columns=["df_two"],
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([idx_one, idx_two]),
)

xlabels = [
    df_one.index.get_level_values(0).tolist(),
    df_one.index.get_level_values(1).tolist(),
]

# plotly

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, y_title="some shared y-title")

fig.append_trace(
    go.Bar(
        y=df_one["df_one"],
        x=[*range(len(df_one["df_one"]))],
        name="df_one",
        showlegend=False,
        text=df_one["df_one"],
        textposition='auto',
        textangle=0,
        texttemplate='%{text:+.1f}',
        offset=-0.9,
    ),
    row=1, col=1,
)

fig.append_trace(
    go.Bar(
        y=df_two["df_two"],
        x=xlabels,
        name="df_two",
        showlegend=False,
        text=df_two["df_two"],
        textposition='auto',
        textangle=0,
        texttemplate='%{text:+.1f}',
    ),
    row=2, col=1,
)

fig.update_xaxes(
    row=1, col=1,
    tickmode = "array",
    tickvals = [*range(len(df_one["df_one"]))],
    range=[
        -1,
        len(df_one["df_one"])-1,
    ]
)

fig.show()
```